# How to edit an old version in Google Appsscripts

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment

I was looking info related to deployment and edit of different versions in new Google AppsScript editor.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#edit_a_versioned_deployment

I noticed that you can "edit and deploy" older versions but when I do that I noticed that the scripts doesn't change.

Before changes
[image: Before changes]

After changes

[image: After changes]

Here I update the version.

[image]
[image]

Then I try to edit the old one.
[image]
[image]

But the script doesn't change, I mean, at this part I would expect to see what I wrote in the first image.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Google just decided that's the way it's going to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Editing a versioned deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#edit_a_versioned_deployment) doesn't change the current script code. It just changes that deployment code, so you can use it as an add-on, a web app, or what have you, but it doesn't revert your current code to that version.

The old editor did have the functionality you are looking for (clicking `File > See verstion history > Restore`), but not the new one. There's a feature request in Issue Tracker to add this to the new editor, consider [subscribing to it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe):

- [Restore an old version in Google Apps Script's new editor](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236721237)